Combine IF for text with INDEX and MATCH? Or VLOOKUP? QUERY?
Coming back to the best source I know to ask for help with something I'm trying to do for our little school. I have one sheet where I enter the date and the name of the student under what they're supposed to do for dismissal (car rider, bus, or aftercare). But teachers are finding it too difficult to go through many students at one to find their own, so I'd like them to each have their own tab with only their students. So a function should pull the name of the student from "Changes," match it to the "Student Reference" tab, then put it on the tab of the teacher in charge of that student.
I can just barely manage INDEX and MATCH alone, and conditions alone, but can't even start to figure out how to go about what I want to do, even though surely it must be possible.
Thank you soooo much in advance for any help! This site has taught me so much.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tyqGMYk_IlSiQ2Rw9BpeKQqGn8HAB-5OQX7ybA4lfy4/edit?usp=sharing

Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.


Try this formula in Cell_A2 of JANE tab. Change the teacher name within the formula while applying it to the other tabs:
=reduce(torow(,1),sequence(1,3,1,2),lambda(a,c,ifna(hstack(a,ifna(filter(choosecols(Changes!A:F,c,c+1),xlookup(choosecols(Changes!A:F,c+1),'Student Reference'!D:D,'Student Reference'!C:C,)="JANE"),wraprows(,2,))))))



I was just starting to wonder about lambda, which I don't understand at all yet but have used before. This works brilliantly!! Thank you so much. I'm enjoying learning, but it takes about two years for me to make any sense out of a new (to me) function. Thank you again!!!
